# href link inside modal is not working

Tags: html, css, href, bootstrap-modal

I have a Modal in my webpage which uses Bootstrap. I've added anchor tags in it to which there are href links. When I am trying to click on that anchor element, it is not clickable. Anchor tag is not working in Modal.

Please help me with this issue.

Please find below code -

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="editionsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="hingoli.html" data-target="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <div style="padding:15px; color:#181818; text-align: center; ">
                                <h4>Hingoli</h4>
                            </div>
                            <img src="pages/hingoli/1.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" class="modal-img" alt="">
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="parbhani.html" class="portfolio-link" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <div style="padding:15px; color:#181818; text-align: center; ">
                                <h4>Parbhani</h4>
                            </div>
                            <img src="pages/parbhani/1.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" class="modal-img" alt="">
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove data-target="#" from the anchor tag.

Comment: not working even after removing data-target="#" from the anchor tag

Comment: Make sure those files which you are calling are in the same folder. Please check the structure.

Comment: Added modal-body class in `<div class="row">` to make it `<div class="row modal-body">` and it worked. Anyways, thanks man. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same behaviour with Bootstrap 4 and it turns out that `.modal-dialog` div has a `pointer-events: none;` attribute that disables the links. Setting to `pointer-events: all;` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this
`$("#yourModalID table tbody").on('click','.yourBtnClass', function(){ //do something here })`

Answer (score 0):

Check it, I used clearfix div. but if I don't want clearfix, then I use
(div `class="modal-body col-sm-3"`) because link divs have a float value
but `modal-body` doesn't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editionsModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="editionsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="hingoli.html" data-target="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <div style="padding:15px; color:#181818; text-align: center; ">
                                <h4>Hingoli</h4>
                            </div>
                            <img src="pages/hingoli/1.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" class="modal-img" alt="">
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="parbhani.html" class="portfolio-link" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <div style="padding:15px; color:#181818; text-align: center; ">
                                <h4>Parbhani</h4>
                            </div>
                            <img src="pages/parbhani/1.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" class="modal-img" alt="">
                        </a>

                    </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code!

```
$('#editionsModal .container a').on('click',function( ev){
  var $button=$(ev.target);
  ev.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(e){
    var $href=$button.attr('href');
    window.location.href=$href;
    });
});
```

Comment: Per the comments, it appears that the OP already found a much simpler answer by adding the `modal-body` class to their `row` container.